# SwiftUI: Subviews move up and down when wrapped in NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to implement a custom TabView, and this is what I get when accessing it via NavigationLink or wrapping it in NavigationView. I've found no info on how to fix it.

[image: screen recording]

I've tried wrapping TabView in other Views and changing it's position in NavigationView hierarchy, and the only result I get is different elements of HomeView start to move against each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [`.animation(nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:)-7mq1i) to the custom `TabView` resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I almost lost my mind over this.